# What means and how to fix errorcode 1 using php exec() and ghostscript?

Tags: php, exec, ghostscript

I try to put together pdf files to one file using php exec() and ghostscript (gs).

I've tried out following code locally (MAMP, PHP 7.x, Mac, gs 9.23) with about 5000 PDF files and everything
works great: one pdf is created out of the 5000 in: files/ovmext/sample.pdf.

```
echo exec('sudo gs -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -q -sDEVICE=pdfwrite - dPDFSETTINGS=/prepress -sOutputFile=files/ovmext/sample.pdf files/wkhtmltopdf/pdf-sample-1.pdf files/wkhtmltopdf/pdf-sample-2.pdf ...  files/wkhtmltopdf/pdf-sample-5000.pdf', $array, $return_var);

if ($return_var == 0) {
   echo 'works! - ' . 'statuscode: ' . $return_var; 
} else {
   echo 'does not work! - ' . 'statuscode: ' . $return_var . ' - ';
   var_dump($return_var); 
}
```

However, when I try to execute the same script on our live server (Apache, PHP 5.x, linux, gs 9.23)
I get Error Status: "1" printed out.

When I just:

```
echo exec('gs -v');
```

everthing works fine and I get the version number etc. of gs.

What is this status code saying and how to fix this?

Comment: Your server didn't grant `sudo` privileges to Apache user I bet.  Nor would I EVER recommend giving `sudo` to Apache user.  Just imagine the havok a hacker would do with a sudo Apache

Comment: The status code is saying "there was an error". There are probably clues in the output of the command, which you appear to store in `$array`. If you `var_dump($array);` what does that say?

Comment: When I `var_dump($array)` I've got: `array(0) { }`